# infinitely many group morphisms $\phi: \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}/ \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Hi we were to prove two things.
On the one hand that there is only one group morphism $\phi: (\mathbb{Q}/ \mathbb{Z},+) \to (\mathbb{Q},+)$. This was quite easy due to the fact that each element of $\mathbb{Q}/ \mathbb{Z}$ had a finite order and the fact that zero maps to zero.
On the other hand we had to prove that there are infinitely many group morphisms $\phi: (\mathbb{Q},+ )\to (\mathbb{Q}/ \mathbb{Z},+)$. One morphism I could think of is the natural morphism $f: (\mathbb{Q},+ )\to (\mathbb{Q}/ \mathbb{Z},+): \frac{a}{b} \to \frac{a}{b} + \mathbb{Z}.$ Now we can take a random $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ so we have another group morphism $f': (\mathbb{Q},+ )\to (\mathbb{Q}/ \mathbb{Z},+): \frac{a}{b} \to \frac{a}{b} + n + \mathbb{Z}.$ And since there are infinitely many whole numbers to choose from there infinitely many morphisms. Is this correct? Or since $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ it's not really a different morphism?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150793/discussion-on-question-by-rikdb-infinitely-many-group-morphisms-phi-mathbbq); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The group homomorphisms $\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}$ have the form $\varphi_q(x)=qx$ for any $q \in \mathbb{Q}$.

If we compose with the natural quotient map $\pi : \mathbb{Q}\to \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ given by $\pi(x) = x + \mathbb{Z}$, we get $\pi \circ \varphi_q$, each of which is a different homomorphism.

Comment: P.S. for the OP: It might be worth taking a second or two to think about why this doesn't give you infinitely many homomorphisms the other direction since you can do the same composition...

Answer (score 0):

HINT: For any positive integer $n$, check that $\phi_n: \frac{a}{b} \mapsto$ $\frac{an \pmod b}{b}$ [and then reduce the numerator and denominator until they are relatively prime] is a group morphism, where $\frac{a}{b} \in \mathbb{Q}$ with $\gcd(a,b)=1$.

To see that $\{\phi_n; n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is indeed an infinite set [and indeed, that $\phi_n \not = \phi_{n'}$ for $n \not = n'$], note that for any prime $b$, the morphisms $\phi_1,\ldots, \phi_{b-1}$ are distinct. Indeed, check how each such $\phi_n$; $n=1,2,\ldots, b-1$ acts on $\{\frac{a}{b}; \gcd(a,b)=1\}$. And then use the fact that there are an infinite number of primes, and in particular, a prime $b > \max\{n,n'\}$, to conclude that $\phi_n$ and $\phi_{n'}$ are distinct for positive integers $n,n'$ with $n \not = n'$.

Comment: thanks very clear